# Firebase Realtime Database Connection Delay

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-connection

I have been working with Firebase Realtime Database for past couple of days, and it seems on some of the devices like Samsung, Honor 6x It's taking random amount of time to connect to Firebase Realtime Database. With the same code on device like Nexus, Red Mi, HTC Firebase Realtime Databse connects instantly with same network bandwidth.

Sample code is here

```
Pruduct product = new Product(1,"Test");
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("product").child("test-123").setValue("product");
```

I am also checking the connection status by below code

```
DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
        if (connected) {                           
            System.out.println("firebase connected");
        } else {
                System.out.println("firebase not connected");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        System.err.println("firebase Listener was cancelled");
    }
});
```

Edit - 1

Below are the logs when `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);` enable.

```
D/RepoOperation: set: /test/test-193
D/DataOperation: set: /test/test-193 {
               data=true
               data1=22.99
               data2=72.49
               data3=1515128372
             }
D/Connection: conn_0 - Sending data: {d={a=p, r=24, b={d={data1=22.99, data3=1515128372, data2=72.49, data=true}, p=test/test-193}}, t=d}
D/WebSocket: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 33317
D/RepoOperation: Aborting transactions for path: /test/test-193. Affected: /test/test-193
```

Comment: The best way to troubleshoot is to [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) in your app and see if the logcat output contains any hints on why establishing the connection is taking so much time.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have edited my question with the logs, but from this I am not able to reach to any conclusion. Please have a look.

Comment: There should be a lot more happening *before* your actual write operation goes through. Also note that it's hard to gauge performance without seeing the timestamps on those logs.